# CSS Bootstrap 4 - making multiple line row with equal columns

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a multiple line row with equal width columns with Bootstrap 4. This is the loop where I am creating this columns:

```
 <div class="row video-section">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      @if(!(count($videos) > 0))
      <p>{{ $player->first_name }} {{ $player->last_name }} has no videos yet.</p>
      @else
      @foreach($videos as $video)
      <div class="col-md-3 profile-video-box">
        <a href="/player/video/{{ $video->uid }}/{{ $video->player->fullName }}">
          <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
            <img src="{{ $video->getThumbnail() }}" class="card-img"/>
            <div class="card-img-overlay">
              <div class="play-icon-wrapper">
                <i class="ion-ios-play"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ $video->title != '' ?  $video->title : 'Untitled' }}
                </h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ $video->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
```

But, then the each column takes up the whole row, since it gets the margin right to take up the rest of the space in the row. How can I fix that and create multiple line row?

**Update**

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19prmrL6/).

Comment: It would give more idea to user if you add image what exactly happens. If possible add exact values that we can try and provide you solution!

Comment: @Paulie_D I have made a fiddle if things were unclear, I thought it was easy to understand what I mean, sorry for that.

Comment: @Leff Its not correct to use `col-lg-12` with `row`, Instead you can see my answer below. Just read the bootstrap doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19prmrL6/4/)

```
        <div class="row video-section ">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 profile-video-box">
                    123
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 profile-video-box">
                    456
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 profile-video-box">
                    759
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Its not right to use `col-lg-12` with `row`. Don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `<div class="col-md-12">` inside your `<div class="row video-section">` element. Instead confine `<div class="col-md-12">` to only your `<p>` tag, like:

```
<div class="row video-section">
  @if(!(count($videos) > 0))
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>{{ $player->first_name }} {{ $player->last_name }} has no videos yet.</p>
  </div>
  @else
  @foreach($videos as $video)
  <div class="col-md-3 profile-video-box">
    <a href="/player/video/{{ $video->uid }}/{{ $video->player->fullName }}">
      <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
        <img src="{{ $video->getThumbnail() }}" class="card-img"/>
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <div class="play-icon-wrapper">
            <i class="ion-ios-play"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ $video->title != '' ?  $video->title : 'Untitled' }}
            </h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ $video->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Hope this helps!